# Errors and difficulties with: Keras generators with h5 data: Cancelled operations

Tags: keras

I'm experiencing many errors/problems with Keras generators and multi-processing.

I have used:

```
history = model.fit(training_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=trainingSetSize // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=validationGenerator,
        validation_steps= validationSetSize // batch_size,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        workers=nb_workers,
        max_queue_size=2*nb_workers)
```

to launch the training.

My generator spits batches of (batch_size,64,64,2) tensors. One problem is that I notice the following warnings/error messages:

```
Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled
```

even though I added the steps_per_epoch = X_size // batch_size,

Also by adding a print() inside the generator I notice that at the end of an epoch, it generates an "empty" tensor of shape: (0,64,64,2)...

Any ideas, any proposals/comments/answers?

this is the generator's code:

```
class custom_gen(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, fn, datasetSize, batch_size, trainingsetName,trainingsetTargetsName):
        self.fn=fn
        self.datasetSize= datasetSize
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.trainingsetTargetsName = trainingsetTargetsName
        self.trainingsetName = trainingsetName
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    #compulsory method: total number of batches that the generator must produce
    def __len__(self):
        return self.datasetSize // self.batch_size

    #idx arg is managed by Python/Keras by themselves!?
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        with self.lock:
            f=h5py.File(self.fn,'r')    
            X=f[self.trainingsetName][idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
            Y=f[self.trainingsetTargetsName][idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]


            print('Generated X.shape='+str(X.shape))
            print('Generated Y.shape='+str(Y.shape))
            return X,Y
```

Comment: Note: I updated the __len__ func to: return self.datasetSize // self.batch_size, but I still get the error message : 2020-04-05 19:13:55.902774: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled

Comment: All looks oorrect, prints show integer number of steps per epochs etc. And the network seems to train, but I am embarrased by this annoying (disturbing) error message ..